# Is passing a user's ID to JavaScript using wp_localize_script secure?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I am attempting to recover a WordPress user's ID on the backend PHP after receiving an AJAX post request.

I was unable to use wp_get_current_user() within my AJAX handler function on the backend (I'm not entirely sure why this fails)

My solution was to use wp_localize_script to pass wp_get_current_user()->ID to the browser. I am concerned that the user might be able to change the user ID within their browser and pose as another user. Is this possible? If so, is there a better way to get the user's ID in an ajax POST?

The following is my current setup:

**JS Ajax**

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('user_id', ajax_object.user_id);
fd.append('action', 'tb_upload');

jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
        data: fd,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,

        success: function (resp) {
            console.log("in success!");
            if (resp != null) {
                console.log(resp.data);
            } else {
                console.log("Error: Response is null!");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Anything that isn't serverside can be accessed.

Comment: @amarinediary Which is fine by me; I just want to make sure that the user cannot alter the user ID on their side and, when sent back to the server, pose as another user.